# Is there some kind of malloc library providing interface to free memory back to os?

Tags: malloc

I don't know whether there is a malloc library that providing interface to free-ed memory back to os when calling it.....
If there is no, what can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Under some operating systems, you can use `sbrk` to reduce the size of your arena. This may or may not hand that memory back to the OS.

In today's world of virtual memory, it may not really be necessary. There's a good chance that, if you just stop using the memory, it'll get swapped out and never bought back in to main storage (although it may still take up address space and swap file space) - that all depends on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It should happen automatically on `free()`, but sometimes an explicit `malloc_trim()` helps:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html